# Is it possible to write custom prefix operators in R? (Why not?)

Tags: r, operators, prefix-operator

it is "common" in R to define custom infix operators, such as

```
`%op%` <- function(e1, e2) someOperation(e1, e2)
result <- e1 %op% e2
```

It seems to be impossible to define an unary operator (corresponding to e.g. the `!`):

(for a minimal example:)

```
`%op%` <- function(x) x
# the definition works fine
`%op%`
# function(x) x
# but usage fails
%op% x
# Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%op%"
```

However the `!` operator itself appears to be defined in the same way, at least as far as the user sees:

```
`!`
# function (x)  .Primitive("!")
```

But apparently the internals are different, since my function doesn't work. Is there a specific reason for this? Or is there another way to do it that I'm unaware of? (I can not recall any package or such that offers an unary prefix operator, so likely the answer is it doesn't work...)

Comment: I've got hrbrmstr's infix functions [gist](https://gist.github.com/hrbrmstr/58b827dea95a7adf0f0e751b44b75b0c) in my bookmarks toolbar as a reminder to learn how to do these...can't say I've gotten around to figuring them out yet

Comment: Actually your unary operator _does_ work. However, unfortunately not as an operator but as a function `\`%op%\`(1)`. I would rather see the infix operator as an exception to the rule than the standard. Eventually, the infix operator is a function in its own. For instance `\`%in%\`(1:3, 1:4)` is valid R code.